# How can tell if I'll get a free point in a skill once I meet its prerequisite?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

At least twice so far, I've put points in a skill to meet the prerequisite for other skills, and upon meeting that prerequisite, I got a free point in the new "unlocked" skill. Other times, though, I've gotten no free points.

For example, after my alchemist put 5 points in Fire Formula, he did not get a free point in Inferno Formula. Nor did my Gunner get a free point in High Caliber after putting a point in ATK Up. However, my Protector got a free point in Fire Wall, Ice Wall, and Volt Wall after putting her third point in Shield Mastery

Is there a way I can tell which skills I'll get free points in and which I won't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prerequisite for a skill is a Mastery Skill then putting enough points into the Master Skill to unlock a new skill will give you a free point in said skill.

Comment: Okay, as I've leveled up this is **definitely** how it works. Every time I've unlocked a skill with a mastery pre-req I've gotten one point in the skill for free. This has **never** happened with any other skills and pre-reqs.